Async method call in MySFTPServer __init__ method
I need to get the path of the chroot of the user from the database. This is how I use my sftp server to create server.
await asyncssh.create_server(
        MySSHServer, '', PORT,
        server_host_keys=['/Users/mrtplt`your text`/.ssh/id_rsa'],
        process_factory=lambda: None,  # No shell support
        sftp_factory=lambda chan: MySFTPServer(chan, db),  
        allow_scp=True,
        kex_algs=[
            'curve25519-sha256', 'curve25519-sha256@libssh.org', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp256',
            'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1'
        ],
        encryption_algs=[
            'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr'
        ],
        mac_algs=[
            'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512'
        ],
        compression_algs=['none']
    )

This is how I implemented sftp server. the problem is at the get account by username method. That method should be asynchronous. I couldn't make init method asynchronous.
Copilot suggested me to create a create factory method that returns the instance of mysftpserver. But in that case the code block above doesn't work.
class MySFTPServer(asyncssh.SFTPServer):
    def __init__(self, chan: asyncssh.SSHServerChannel, db: 'Database'):
        self._chan = chan
        self._db = db
        self._username = chan.get_extra_info('username')
        super().__init__(chan)
        username = self._username
        logger.debug(f"Fetching account data for username: {username}")
        home_folder = await self._db.get_account_by_username(username)
        print(f"Account data: {home_folder}")
        if home_folder:
            os.makedirs(home_folder, exist_ok=True)
            logger.info(f"Establishing root_folder for {username} at: {home_folder}")
            self.set_chroot(home_folder)
        else:
            logger.error(f"Account for username {username} not found in the database or data is incomplete.")
            raise ValueError(f"Account for username {username} not found in the database or data is incomplete.")   

How can I change chroot of the sftp user retrieved from the database during the initialization?
I see ssh classes has connection_made method but SFTP subclasses doesn't, so I cannot change the users chroot after initialization.
thank you for your help.
Asyncssh document doesnt indicate connection_made method
